# PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS is not visible in cloud service

Tags: azure

I am unable to get PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS of cloud service. In azure portal it is showing blank. How do i enable it ?

Comment: is it a cloud app or azure websites? or a VM?

Comment: it is a cloud service which contains a worker role.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no InputEndpoints defined in your service definition then the portal won't show the VIP.  But the cloud service will still have a VIP and you can find it by using nslookup, ping, etc on the DNS name (*.cloudapp.net).

Comment: I tried to ping the URL but still didn't got results.The problem got resolved and IP address started appearing when i clicked and option of "Enabling remote desktop for all roles". Then you also need to fill sign in details for login and a certificate thumbprint is necessary.

Comment: The reason the VIP showed up after enabling RDP is that RDP turns on a public endpoint (port 3389).  Ping definitely does work, but without more details I can't guess as to why it didn't work for you.